# Bash Scripting; giving commands to programs stdin

Tags: bash, scripting, sh, chroot

I am very new to bash scripting. I have the following script:

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /var/chroot/etc/apt/sources.list
chroot /var/chroot/
apt-get update
apt-get --simulate install $a > output
```

I actually want the last 2 comands to be run in chroot environment but I do not know how to give it to it, I searched but I could not find. I also want chroot to exit after execution of the commands, but it currently hangs. What can I do to prevent this?

**EDIT:** For future visitors:

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /var/chroot/etc/apt/sources.list
chroot /var/chroot apt-get update > /dev/null
chroot /var/chroot apt-get --simulate install nodejs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you want to run in the `chroot` environment must be given to `chroot` as an argument. See the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot).